Stable categories are tensored over spectra
It's a folklore result by Lurie that for a (presentable) stable $\infty$-category $\mathscr{C}$ the mapping space functor $\mathsf{Map}:\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \times \mathscr{C} \to \mathsf{An}$ enhances to a mapping spectrum functor $\mathsf{map}:\mathscr{C}^{\mathrm{op}} \times \mathscr{C} \to \mathsf{Sp}$.
Does this participate in an adjunction that makes $\mathscr{C}$ tensored over $\mathsf{Sp}$? I.e. is there a functor $\otimes$ with an equivalence $$ \mathsf{Map}_{\mathsf{Sp}}(X, \mathsf{map}_{\mathscr{C}}(c,c')) \simeq \mathsf{Map}_{\mathscr{C}}(X \otimes c, c')?$$ By [Lur17, 4.8.2.18] we know that $\mathscr{C}$ corresponds to an object of $\mathsf{Mod}_{\mathsf{Sp}}(\mathsf{Pr}^L)$. Does this automatically imply the tensoring statement? I couldn't find anything of this sort in Gepner-Groth-Nikolaus but maybe I didn't look hard enough.
A reference would be enough for me.

You should perhaps say that [Lur17] is Higher Algebra, for the "uninitiated" :)

@BenSteffan You're right but I figured that anyone who doesn't recognize [Lur17] as "Higher Algebra" most likely won't be familiar enough with the content of the question. In particular, an ideal answer to the question is likely of the form "See [Lur 17, ???]."!

There should be a way to just derive this from the fact that $\mathscr{C}$ is canonically an object in $\mathsf{Mod}_\mathsf{Sp}(\mathsf{Pr}^L)$, as you said. I was thinking along the lines of "We are given a morphism $\mathsf{Sp}\otimes\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}$. and morphisms in $\mathsf{Pr}^L$ have right adjoints, and surely we get the hom-enrichment via this right adjoint". However, because I am not cool enough to figure out the details of that, and because I want to show that you don't need presentability of $\mathscr{C}$, allow me to prove your question via a direct check.
Given $c\in\mathscr{C}$ and $K\in\mathsf{Sp}$, define $K\otimes c :\simeq\mathrm{colim}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left((\Omega^{\infty-n}K\otimes c)[-n]\right)\in\mathscr{C}$, where given $\require{enclose}\enclose{updiagonalstrike}{\mathrm{a\;space}}$ an anima $X$, we write $X\otimes c:\simeq\mathrm{colim}_X\,c\in\mathscr{C}$. Note that our formula for $K\otimes c$ recovers in case $\mathscr{C} \simeq\mathsf{Sp}$ the tensor product of spectra. Note also that this definition is a direct analogue of the way every $\infty$-category with colimits is tensored over $\mathsf{An}$. Once we have turned this construction into a functor $\mathsf{Sp}\otimes\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{C}, (K,c)\mapsto K\otimes c$, we can write down for $K\in\mathsf{Sp}$ and $c,d\in\mathscr{C}$ a natural chain of equivalences (motivated later)
$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{C} (K\otimes c,d)&\simeq\mathrm{lim}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\left(\mathscr{C}(c,d[n])^{\Omega^{\infty-n}K}\right)\\
&\simeq\mathrm{lim}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,\mathsf{An}(\Omega^{\infty-n}K,\mathscr{C}(c,d[n]))\\
&\simeq\mathrm{lim}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,\mathsf{An}(\Omega^{\infty-n}K,\Omega^{\infty-n}\mathsf{map}_\mathscr{C}(c,d))\\
&\simeq\mathsf{Sp}(K,\mathsf{map}_\mathscr{C}(c,d)).
\end{align}
$$
These steps are justified as follows: the first equivalence is clear (for an anima $X$ and an object $Y$ in an $\infty$-category with sufficient limits, $Y^X$ means $\mathrm{lim}_{X}\,Y$). The second equivalence follows as $Y^X\simeq\mathsf{An}(X,Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are anima; this follows after writing $X\simeq\mathrm{colim}_X\,*$. The third we will talk about below. The last equivalence follows as mapping anima in a limit of $\infty$-categories is computed as a limit of the respective mapping anima in the relevant diagram. Since we have a natural equivalence $$\mathscr{C}(K\otimes c,d)\simeq\mathsf{Sp}(K,\mathsf{map}_\mathscr{C}(c,d)),$$ we have the desired tensoring of $\mathscr{C}$ over $\mathsf{Sp}$.
We must still explain why $\Omega^{\infty-n}\mathsf{map}_\mathscr{C}(c,d)\simeq\mathscr{C}(c,d[n])$. Given a left exact functor $F\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{D}$, where $\mathscr{D}$ is an $\infty$-category with finite limits, we know that $F$ lifts along $\Omega^\infty\colon\mathsf{Sp}(\mathscr{D})\to\mathscr{D}$ to an exact functor $f\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathscr{D}$, because $\mathscr{C}$ is stable itself. This functor $f$ is given by $\Omega^{\infty-n}(fc)\simeq F(c[n])$. (This makes sense: since $F$ is left exact, you can check that $\Omega^nF(c[n])\simeq Fc$, so the collection $(F(c[n])_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ does define a spectrum object in $\mathscr{D}$.) Taking $F$ to be the functor $\mathscr{C}(c,-)\colon\mathscr{C}\to\mathsf{Fun}(\mathscr{C}^\mathrm{op},\mathsf{An})$, this tells us that $\mathsf{map}_\mathscr{C}(c,-)$ satisfies $\Omega^{\infty-n}\mathsf{map}_\mathscr{C}(c,d)\simeq\mathscr{C}(c,d[n])$, as needed.

You're pretty cool in my eyes ;-)
